# fullscreen api make fullscreen element with internal elements and save ability to work dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Can I use fullscreen API to make fullscreen any element with many internal element and save ability to work dropdown and other custom element, parts of which  are in different locations of page?

Eg div with dropdowns(eg https://code.google.com/p/ufd/), when I make this div fullscreen, then dropdown will not work(dropdown still working, but dropdowns list of items are hidden behind div).

I want that dropdown still work as without fullscreen.

Can I do so? Change z-index of dropdown list and other element is not suitable.

Comment: may be you need to set some z-index value.

Comment: Change z-index of other elements is not suitable, because on fullscreened element is many different controls/element. and impossible guess that there will be added. Do you know another way or it does not exist? I want find common solution of this problem

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown element is most likely being attached to an element that is not a descendent of the fullscreen element (eg. the document body). If this is the case, you could use a Mutation Observer to watch for specific elements (ie. the dropdown element) being added to the document body and move them under the fullscreen element.

```
fullscreenMutationObserver: MutationObserver;

requestFullscreen(fullscreenElement) {

    if(document.fullscreenElement) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
      if(this.fullscreenMutationObserver) {
        this.fullscreenMutationObserver.disconnect();
      }
      return;
    }
    
    fullscreenElement.requestFullscreen();

    this.fullscreenMutationObserver = new MutationObserver(mutationRecords => {
      mutationRecords.forEach(mutationRecord => {
        mutationRecord.addedNodes.forEach(node => {
          if(node.isTheDropdownElementWeAreLookingFor()) {
            document.body.removeChild(node);
            document.querySelector(':fullscreen').appendChild(node);
          }
        });
      });
    });

    this.fullscreenMutationObserver.observe(document.body, { childList: true });
}
```